# xsl 1.0, count if more than 2 elements then change css class

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The data comes from the server, usually two rows, but sometimes it's more. So I try to make the list dynamic change.

```
    <xsl:template match="Event">
        <ul class="lines">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Line"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Line">
        <li class="something">
            <a href="">
                <span class="result"><xsl:value-of select="@result"/></span>
                <span class="odds"><xsl:value-of select="@odds"/></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

I have to count the number of "li" and if it's more than 2, i have to change the class of "li"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the template matching `Line` you can access the total number of `Line` elements within this `Event` using the `last()` function (which returns the index number of the last node in the "current node list" determined by the `select` expression of the `apply-templates` that caused this template to fire, which in this case is the set of `Line` children of a particular `Event`).

```
<li>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="last() &lt;= 2">something</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>somethingElse</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="Event">
    <ul class="lines">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Line"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line" name="Line">
    <xsl:param name="classVal" select="'something'" />
    <li class="{$classVal}">
      <a href="">
        <span class="result">
          <xsl:value-of select="@result"/>
        </span>
        <span class="odds">
          <xsl:value-of select="@odds"/>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line[count(../Line) > 1]">
    <xsl:call-template name="Line">
      <xsl:with-param name="classVal" select="'somethingElse'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```